# Should Store in shared preferences or sqlite in OnDestroy?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-lifecycle

I have a countdownTimer ProgressBar in my activity , I need to save the timepassed and few arraylists if the user destroys the activity, so that when it is recreated within the countdownTimer span, I can start from where it was stopped. But im Confused to save in sqlite or shared preferences? I searched and saw shared preference as better option but how can I save arraylist in shared preference??

Comment: use gson library to save arraylist in shared preferences

Comment: Any other way. Im not using Gson at the moment. and wouldnt like to include the library just for this. Can u rather help me and tell how to convert arraylist to Json String

Comment: Yes, you can save arraylist on `SharedPreferences` but remember, if a user clear app data or have a root device, he/she can see your data or delete it.

Comment: *wouldnt like to include the library just for this* do it anyway. Don't reinvent the wheel. Use what is out there. Gson is a small library

Comment: save them in a file then which would be more typical to do

Comment: I agree with @TimCastelijns,  *Don't reinvent the wheel*, but you can use `HashSet` instead of  `Gson Library`

Comment: @Aspicas : so u suggest sqlite? But how would i shift arraylist to db and back again?

Comment: Beware that there are instances when `onDestroy()` won't be called.

Comment: mmm... `sqlite?`... I don't know if you need store a important data... you must decide if it's important and choose the best option...anyway, if its a important data and your user had a root device, he/she can see you database also.. Encrypt your data too on database if it's a important data.

Comment: Note that wiping app data also removes any sqlite or other database, so that's no valid argument

Comment: @Aspicas : Thanks for the help. 2

Comment: Yeah... of course, if an user clear app data, he/she removes all databases...